# How to page through an array

Tags: php

I'd like to know how to page through an array. I want to pass an integer value into a function and have that function return that many rows of the array. If there are additional rows, then they need to be paged or limited as well by the integer value that was passed into the function.

Can someone help me get this down?

Comment: Please post the code you have written so far. People generally do not like to just write your code for you. As it is, this is a work description, not a question.

Comment: Might be handy if you post some example code... even if its 'pseudo code', array before and after examples too.

Answer (score 6):

There is already a function for that:

```
= array_slice($array, $page * 10, 10);
// would return a block of ten array entries
```

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to know how to page through an array.

Where do you get the array from? In my experience, arrays generally come from a data source such as a database. In such a case, I would suggest you simply use SQL to limit the number of returned rows;

```
SELECT your, fields FROM yourtable LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10;
```

Hope that might help you or anyone having the same issues.